# Objects do not land on the floor in unreal engine 5

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, unreal-engine5

Objects do not land on the floor and fall straight down, how can I solve this?
When I place an object in the air and press the Run button, it does not land on the floor and falls straight down. How can I resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several conditions need to be met:

- All actors (those that fall and those don't fall) have a static mesh, and the static meshes have collision (more info [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/setting-up-collisions-with-static-meshes-in-unreal-engine/))
- All the actors that need to fall have Mobility set to "Movable" (more info [here)](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/actor-mobility-in-unreal-engine/) and "Simulate Physics" set to "true"
- All the actors that don't need to fall have "Static" mobility

See first half of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOkSAEkIkjs) if you need a step by step.